# Setting up and deploying Cookiecutter-Django project on Heroku, with Docker: Deploy fails, Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: django, docker, heroku, deployment, cookiecutter-django

I am tying to deploy a cookiecutter project, using docker and git to Heroku. I followed the steps here: https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment-on-heroku.html and everything works until I Heroku tries to release the deploy. That means I can push everything to the master but then I get the following error:

```
remote: django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
remote: Waiting for release.... failed.
```

I tried to set up a fresh project but I still get the same error. I don't have any apps on my project yet, but just a plain html page. Could that be the cause? Or has anyone any other ideas?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance....

Comment: Firstly, **why** is it not a duplicate? Second, the question is far too broad in any case. What, exactly, about the instructions is not clear?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Daniel. It might be a duplicate. Yet, I am hoping to get some more information o this topic. It is not clear to me if I can just push my docker image to heroku or if I have to set up the project according to this documentation (https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment-on-heroku.html). It is more a question of where I am supposed to start....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload and deploy django cookiecutter project, with docker, to heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48977129/how-to-upload-and-deploy-django-cookiecutter-project-with-docker-to-heroku)

Comment: @Micromegas, again, that's too broad. Have you tried anything? There's plenty of documentation about deploying Docker containers on Heroku. And there are other suggestions in the question you linked. Read through it, try deploying, and come back with a concrete question if you get stuck. Please make sure it's on-topic as defined in the [help/on-topic]. (This _is_ a duplicate, as far as I can tell. I've voted to close it as such.)

Comment: I updated the question accordingly. Any help would be still appreciated